# Unwanted edge outside of the geometry

Tags: modeling

[image: unwanted edge]

I'm sorry, I'm a blender modeling beginner but I don't know why I have an edge floating outside of my geometry that I can't get ride of. I don't know how it got here. I tried "remove doubles" but that didn't do anything. In edit mode, the edge or the vertices can be selected but not deleted.

Thank you

Comment: Can you upload your file?

Answer (score 1):

You have to go into Edit Mode, to be able to delete geometry. 
[image]
Then, click the selection-box with a line. (Directly below the yellow highlighted line). 
[image]
After that, you can select the line you dont want and press the "X" key, and select "Edges" in order to delete the unwanted edge.

Comment: Many thanks. I had done that but it think there was a bug. Restarted Blender and did it again, worked this time.